# Apply different data validation to column based on matching column first cell value

Tags: excel, vba

data validation = (list, decimal, whole number, etc.)

I have a sheet with a column for products (called variant.id, column F), followed by 20 blank attribute columns (H:AA), followed by their corresponding allowed values columns (AG:AZ), with the attribute name as column headers for both. The allowed values are either a vertical list or a single cell word like 'integer', 'inches', 'ounces', etc.  I would like to use VBA to apply data validation list to the attribute columns for which the corresponding allowed values are a list, and data validation decimal (0 to 1000) to the attribute columns whose corresponding allowed values are 'inches', 'ounces', 'pounds', etc. (with input message 'Enter a number in inches, ounces, etc.'), and data validation whole number (0 to 100) to columns with allowed values 'integer' (with input message 'Enter a whole number').

I would like to apply the data validation for the attribute columns stretching down to 50K rows and then clear all for cells which return '#N/A' for a vlookup with a concatenation of variant.id column with column header against a pre-made column (column AD) of that combo in between the attribute columns and allowed values columns.

I realize this is a complicated request and I appreciate any assistance you can offer.

Comment: What is the *specific* problem you're facing when writing the code to do what you describe?  What exactly is preventing you from getting it running?

Comment: I'm just starting out with excel VBA, so I'm not sure how to code this...if you could provide the answer it would help me understand how to tackle these sorts of things in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
Sub Validation()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim list As Range
Dim list2 As Range
Dim list3 As Range
Dim num As Range
Dim num2 As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set SrchRng = Range("ag2:az2")
Set num = Range("ba1")
Set num2 = Range("bb1")
Cells.replace What:="Value Type: xsd:integer", Replacement:="Integer", _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:= _
    False, ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
For Each cel In SrchRng
Set list = Range(cel.Offset(0, 0), cel.Offset(50, 0))
num = WorksheetFunction.CountA(list)
Set list3 = Range("$F3:$F50000")
num2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(list3)
Set list2 = Range(cel.Offset(0, 0), cel.Offset(num - 1, 0))
If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Inches") = 0 And InStr(1, cel.Value, "Integer") = 0 And InStr(1, cel.Value, "Pounds") = 0 And InStr(1, cel.Value, "Ounces") = 0 And InStr(1, cel.Value, "Watts") = 0 Then
    Range(cel.Offset(0, -25), cel.Offset(num2, -25)).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="='" & ws.Name & "'!" & list2.Address
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End If
Next cel
For Each cel In SrchRng
If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Inches") > 0 Then
    Range(cel.Offset(0, -25), cel.Offset(num2, -25)).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
    :=xlBetween, Formula1:="0", Formula2:="1000"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = "Enter a number in inches."
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End If
Next cel
For Each cel In SrchRng
If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Integer") > 0 Then
    Range(cel.Offset(0, -25), cel.Offset(num2, -25)).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="0", Formula2:="100"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = "Enter a whole number."
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End If
Next cel
For Each cel In SrchRng
If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Pounds") > 0 Then
    Range(cel.Offset(0, -25), cel.Offset(num2, -25)).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
    :=xlBetween, Formula1:="0", Formula2:="1000"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = "Enter a number in pounds."
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End If
Next cel
For Each cel In SrchRng
If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Ounces") > 0 Then
    Range(cel.Offset(0, -25), cel.Offset(num2, -25)).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
    :=xlBetween, Formula1:="0", Formula2:="1000"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = "Enter a number in ounces."
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End If
Next cel
For Each cel In SrchRng
If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Watts") > 0 Then
    Range(cel.Offset(0, -25), cel.Offset(num2, -25)).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
    :=xlBetween, Formula1:="0", Formula2:="1000"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = "Enter a number in watts."
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Now I only need to remove validation from cells that return '#N/A' from a vlookup of variantid&columnheader against column AD.  Here is the code I have so far:

I'm trying to use this code to clear cells from just column I:

```
Sub Clear_cells()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("$I$2:$I$50000")
Dim header As String
header = Range("I1").Value
Dim cel As Range
Dim id As String
Dim s As String
Dim val As Range
Set val = Range("bd1")
For Each cel In rng
id = cel.Offset(0, -3).Value
s = id & header
On Error Resume Next
val = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(s, ActiveSheet.Range("$AD:$AD"), 1, 
False)
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(val) Then cel.Clear
Next
End Sub
```

but I get an "object variable or with block variable not set" error for line: id = cel.Offset(0, -3).Value
and s, id, and header = ""

Please help as I've exhausted my capabilities.